# How to understand the hypercohomology of the projective limit of a complex of abelian sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

My situation is the following:

I have an inverse system of complexes of quasicoherent sheaves over a scheme, I know that all quasicoherent sheaves in the limit complex are locally free of finite type. And I would like to prove that the limit of hypercohomology groups is isomorphic to the hypercohomology of the limit complex.

Comment: I like what you are doing. Sadly enough I don't even understand half the words you are writing. Could you explain some?

Comment: Which ones would you like?

Comment: can you explain what you mean with "prove"? This is no joke, I have a strong mathematical background, but I don't understand this word, yet.

Comment: There is a statement that may be useful in EGA. It is discussed in this mathoverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65249/sheaf-cohomology-and-inverse-limits